# Javascript, form, checkbox results into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to get the results from a form - in particular a multicheckbox.

So I want to get the results as a simple array

[2,4,6,5,7]

I've tried these -

```
$('.ids:checked').serialize()
$('.ids:checked').serializeArray()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method to generate the collection and get it as an array using [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method.

```
$('.ids:checked').map(function(){ 
  // return the value, which would be the collection element
  return this.value; 
  // get it as an array
}).get()
```

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  console.log($('input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla1" value="something1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla2" value="something2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla3" value="something3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla4" value="something4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla5" value="something5">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla6" value="something6">
</form>
<button>
Click
</button>
```

---

Or use [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method to iterate and generate array where first argument in callback refers to the element.

```
$.map($('.ids:checked'),function(ele){ 
  // return the value, which would be the array element
  return ele.value; 
});
```

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  console.log($.map($('input:checked'), function(ele) {
    return ele.value;
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla1" value="something1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla2" value="something2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla3" value="something3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla4" value="something4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla5" value="something5">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla6" value="something6">
</form>
<button>
Click
</button>
```

Comment: you should also briefly explain what each function does, even if you're linking to the documentations

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir : nope... it's returns a jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = Array.prototype.map.call($('.ids:checked'), function(item){return item.value;});
```

use the core js array map method and binds it to your jquery object

Comment: `this` won't be what you think it is if you're using the native `Array.prototype.map`!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` pass the object to the callback as argument (`...map(function(item) {/* use item */})`). `jQuery.map` bind the object to the `this` keyword of the callback. You are using `Array.prototype.map` but  using the callback of `jQuery.map`!

Comment: hmm yes I totally forgot to set the args to the callback